# Change label color

Tags: color, theme

I have a model that I created in Blender for a science class, and the project requires that I label the parts. The problem is, the labels appear blue when the object isn't selected, and it's the same shade of blue as the stuff behind it, so the label can't be seen. I can't find any theme option for changing this. Is there a way to change the color of this text in the theme options? If not, is there another way to label things other than in this fashion?

Comment: What do you mean labels, are you talking about names of objects shown in the viewport? As far as I know those respect the same object color theming options to (for selected unselected, grouped, active, etc.). Unfortunately no specific theme color for the name as far as I know. Maybe use actual text objects with names?

Comment: you could use text. shift+a > text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In User Preferences > Themes > 3D View > Wire (found 2nd from the top on the left column), changes the wire and text color. So, no, you won't be able to differentiate between the wire color and the text...

[image]

2. I believe the [MeasureIt](http://www.evermotion.org/articles/show/9489/measureit-measurement-tools-add-on-for-blender) add-on could be used to add labels, but it is not what the add-on is intended for.
3. You could have a text object with a constraint to track to the object's location and another to point its rotation at the camera.